# IllegalStateException : a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST

Tags: java, algorithm, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I'm trying to persist two entities Categorie and Question in a PostgreSQL db with one to many (categorie has many questions and a question is in one categorie).

After a lot of search and trying, adding CascadeType.PERSIST to the both entities is the only solution I found to the error but with CascadeType.PERSIST on the question side the category table we'll be full of duplicates. Is there any better solution because the categories should be unique in the table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Category")
public class Category {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "CID")
  private int categoryId;
  @Column(name = "CNAME")
  private String categoryName;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category" , cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  public List<Question> questions;

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (!(o instanceof Category)) {
      return false;
    }
    Category category = (Category) o;
    return categoryId == category.categoryId
        && getCategoryName().equals(category.getCategoryName())
        && questions.equals(category.questions);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(getCategoryName());
  }
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Question" )
public class Question {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "QID")
  private int id;
 @Column(name = "QText")
  private String question;
@ManyToOne()
  private Category category;



  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (!(o instanceof Question)) {
      return false;
    }
    Question question = (Question) o;
    return getId() == question.getId();
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(getId());
  }
```

```
public persist(){
 EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
      em.getTransaction().begin();
      for (Category c : data.getCategories()) {
        em.persist(c);
      }
      em.getTransaction().commit();
      em.close();
}
```

Comment: can you please give us more information on your problem that you are trying to solve: is it `IllegalStateException` exception or `the category table we'll be full of duplicates`. if it is the later one, can you please add more clarifications on this statement?

Comment: The table of categories should have n categories and each question from the questions table should point to it's categorie using a foreign key but what i'm getting is a table (categories) where for each question the categorie is persisted again so the categories table has the exact amount of rows as the questions instead of heaving n rows wich makes the table full of duplicates and i think this is because of the cascade. is it more clear ?

Comment: For me it not a `cascade` problem : in fact `cascade` is a handy feature from JPA to avoid calling `persist` method on child entities which is in your case `Question` entities and many other handy tasks. For your problem, can you give more information on the `data` variable that you have on the `persist` method, what you obtain in the database and what you expect ?

Comment: the persist method takes a categorie object ( in the code above ) from a list that contains many categories. i obtain questions table like it should be and  categorie table that has for every question a row so it's does not use the fk that in the questions table ( fk_categorieID)

Comment: So if I understand your problem, in `data` variable, you have let say 5 `Category` and for each one you have 3 `Question`. You expect obtaining 5 rows in the `Category` table and 15 rows in the `Question` table. But you obtain 15 rows in each table, isn't ?

Comment: this is exactly what i meant

Comment: OK, can you please show us your implenetation of `equals` and `hashcode` methods ? I think that they are the root cause of your problem

Comment: i've added them to the entities

Answer (score 0):

Without much details it is hard to infer the root of your problems; so if what you want to accomplish is to persist a collection of an entity with a one to many association with another entity, then you surely do it semi brute force programmatically without chasing the problem with your annotations configuration.

First remove all `CascadeType` annotations from your entities.

Then write your persist method as follows:

```java
    public void persist(Collection<Category> categories) {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        
        // Persist all categories first, without persisting the questions
        categories.forEach(cat -> safelyPersistCategory(em, cat));
        // Associated the not yet persisted questions with the persisted categories  
        categories.stream().forEach(cat -> cat.getQuestions().stream().forEach(question -> question.setCategory(cat)));
        // Finally persist each question
        categories.stream().flatMap(cat -> cat.getQuestions().stream()).forEach(question -> em.persist(question));

        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
    }
    
    // Safely persists Category without trying to create a relationship to 
    // potentially not persisted Questions
    private void safelyPersistCategory(EntityManager em, Category category) {
        List<Question> questions = category.getQuestions();
        category.setQuestions(null);
        em.persist(category);
        category.setQuestions(questions);
    }
```

As you can see in the comments in the code you manually:

- Add the `Category` entities to the persistence context safely (without
  associating them to potentially non-managed Questions).
- Then associate these **managed** `Category` entities with their `Question` entities.
- Finally add the `Question` entities to the persistence context.

From there you can commit the transaction.

The reason for this sequence is that the `Question` entity is the owner of the relationship, so it must relate to an **already persisted/managed** entity (`Category`), otherwise it will try to link to create an association to a non-persisted/non-managed entity which would cause problems (and which I suspect was what was happening with your original `IllegalStateException`).

Finally, by persisting the `Category` entities first, you can link the `Question` entities to already managed entities and not create them on the fly.

[Complete code on GitHub](https://github.com/marco-ruiz/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so-common/src/main/java/so/a59080640)

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your response. when I remove all CascadeType I get the IllegalStateException : a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST

Comment: oh, yes; the Category had to be persisted first without references to Questions. I just updated the answer with this consideration

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I have done to fix your problem in my local machine, was to change the type of your entities id: `int` to `Long`

**Working example based on your code :**

*Category entity*

```java
package io.ahenteti.java;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Category")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name = Category.FIND_ALL, query = "SELECT c FROM Category c")})
public class Category {

    public static final String FIND_ALL = "Category.findAll";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CID")
    private Long categoryId;

    @Column(name = "CNAME")
    private String categoryName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    public List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof Category)) {
            return false;
        }
        Category category = (Category) o;
        return categoryId == category.categoryId && getCategoryName().equals(category.getCategoryName()) && questions
                .equals(category.questions);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getCategoryName());
    }
}
```

*Question*

```java
package io.ahenteti.java;

import java.util.Objects;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Question")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name = Question.FIND_ALL, query = "SELECT q FROM Question q")})
public class Question {

    public static final String FIND_ALL = "Question.findAll";
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "QID")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "QText")
    private String question;
    @ManyToOne()
    private Category category;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof Question)) {
            return false;
        }
        Question question = (Question) o;
        return getId() == question.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getId());
    }
}
```

*persistence.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence 
  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
  version="2.2">

  <persistence-unit name="persistence-unit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>io.ahenteti.java.Question</class>
    <class>io.ahenteti.java.Category</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:demo"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

*Main*

```java
package io.ahenteti.java;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence-unit").createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        em.persist(createCategory("C1"));
        em.persist(createCategory("C2"));
        em.persist(createCategory("C3"));
        transaction.commit();
        System.out.println("number of categories in database: " + getAllCategories(em).size());
        System.out.println("number of questions in database: " + getAllQuestions(em).size());
    }

    private static List<Question> getAllQuestions(EntityManager em) {
        TypedQuery<Question> getAllQuestions = em.createNamedQuery(Question.FIND_ALL, Question.class);
        return getAllQuestions.getResultList();
    }

    private static List<Category> getAllCategories(EntityManager em) {
        TypedQuery<Category> getAllCategories = em.createNamedQuery(Category.FIND_ALL, Category.class);
        return getAllCategories.getResultList();
    }

    private static Category createCategory(String category) {
        Category res = new Category();
        res.setCategoryName(category);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            res.getQuestions().add(createQuestion(res, category + " - Q" + i));
        }
        return res;
    }

    private static Question createQuestion(Category category, String question) {
        Question q1 = new Question();
        q1.setQuestion(question);
        q1.setCategory(category);
        return q1;
    }

}
```

*output*

```
number of categories in database: 3
number of questions in database: 15
```

Hope it helps :)